# Time series classification using CNN model, 1D or 2D?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, time-series, cnn

I have a multivariate time series dataset that has the same length for each observation but looking at a different time frame (eg. One might be from January to May and another one might be from August to December). Those variables are assumed to be correlated. I am currently working on applying CNN model for this data to do binary classification. I cannot say much about data but it is like classifying time series with anomalies.

What I know is that usually 1D CNN is used for the time series dataset. But since I have multivariate time series, I can basically format them into the 2D matrix and passed them through 2D CNN too.

Questions I have are

1. For 2D CNN, for example, the location of a dog on the image does not matter. Is it the same for 1D CNN? whether anomaly happens at the beginning of the time series or at the end for each variable?
2. If I were to have 5 variables (5 time series per observations) and they are assumed to have a correlation with each other regarding anomaly, is it more logical to use 1D CNN where kernel spans through whole 5 time series as it convolves or it doesn't really matter and 2D CNN also does the job.
3. Any suggestions on how the model should be developed? I read about the CNN+LSTM model or just LSTM being used for time series classification. Also, I saw a more "traditional" methods of extracting statistical features from time series and use random forest or other machine learning models.